# how to limit the number of characters for strong tag?

Tags: html

can anyone pls tell me "how to limit the number of ccharacters for a product name"

I mean here: `http://laptopsisland.com/shop/c/netbooks/`

Some product names are very big, because of that, iam uanble to see 'shop now' (when I hover it)

This is the code i used for the product name:  `<strong class="below-thumb">[product.name]</strong>`

I tried in google 'how to limit number of charaters for strong tag' , but i didnt found.. iam sorry that iam not much gud at html,.. so anyone can..?

sorry if its a noob qquestion..

Answer (score 0):

you can't..strong tag defines an important text. Whatever your text inside the strong tag will be diplayed. If you want to limit the number of characters use text box. try this:

```
<input type="text" class="below-thumb" value="product_name" maxlength="10">
```

hope this helps you out.

UPDATE: to set the textbox ineditable and remove the border, add these line of codes as an attribute to your textbox.

```
readonly="readonly" style="border:0px"
```

Comment: thxn for ur quick reply.. its showing me textbox, i mean iam able to type there.. can I keep Label tag in place of text?

Comment: yes because it's a text box. if you want it to be ineditable add readonly attribute. if you want to remove the border use css.