# Unable to retrive value from select options

Tags: javascript, html

whenever I try change the value from dropdown, it shud redirect to other URL..

anyway, i just had little issue..

when I try to change the value, iam not getting brand value, its showing me as: 'undefined'

Any Idea?

```
  <select id="brand" onchange="gotoPage()">

        <?php 
          $brands = dfr_get_brands_list($category);
        foreach ($brands as $brand) : ?>

               <option><?php echo $brand; ?></option>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

        </select>


        <?php if (@$_GET['brand']) { ?>


         <a href="[server.url type='fullpage' query='-brand']"><FONT COLOR="red"><?php echo"[[X] Remove Brand "; ?><?php echo @$_GET['brand']; ?></font></a>


        <?php } ?>


        <script>

          function gotoPage(){
            var url = "http://laptopsisland.com/shop/c/laptops/";
            var sel = document.getElementById("brand");
            var brand = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

            alert(brand);

            window.location.href = url + "&brand=" + brand;
        }

          </script>
```

Comment: we can't see the opening select tag (does it have id #brand`?) also: `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value`

Comment: I updated.. anyway I tried using  sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value BUT still not getting..

Answer (score 0):

I would chance your options to show something like this

```
<option value="<?php echo $brand; ?>"><?php echo $brand; ?></option>
```

and then get the selected value as Bokonic mentioned

```
sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value
```

Let me know how that works.

Comment: Make sure `var sel` is defined. let me know

Comment: just do a `alert(sel);` see if the alert says undefined like it did for brand.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the generation code.

You also don't need to use getElementById.

```
<script>
function gotoPage(e) {
    var brand = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(brand);
}
</script>
<select id="brand" onchange="gotoPage(this)">
    <option>aaa</option>
    <option>bbb</option>
</select>
```

Working solution:
 http://jsfiddle.net/2YzAV/2/

Version with values:
http://jsfiddle.net/2YzAV/3/

Comment: Your both versions getting 'undefined'  only! Even i tried keeping name attribute too, but still not working...

Comment: Sorry, it just works. I have no idea what you do to break it. Are you running the fiddle and clicking there? Or does it break when you put it in your code?

Comment: i have kepted ur code in mine and tested.. then its not working.. but in jsfiddle, ur code working...

BTW, could u reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277280/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-for-strong-tag

can i use label? if  so, how?

and here too bro pls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278385/how-to-increase-the-width-of-my-template

Comment: edit your post and paste the code that results from you using my answer. I need to see what you did (I guess you skipped the word `this` or something). Also note that your questions get downvoted. Try reading some suggestions from stackoverflow on how they should look and edit them. It really helps. And look for some introduction to html5 apps. Your questions are really specific and there's not much room to tell you that your app should not work that way at all. Anyway, I'll try to help, but you might have to wait for me a day or two.