# How to increase the width of my template?

Tags: html, css

I am thinking to increase the width of my template.

Website: laptopsisland.com

Here is the css code for site width.

```
/**************** MAIN WIDTH *********************/
.wrapper { padding: 0; min-width:960px }              
.boxed-layout .wrapper  { width:1000px; background: #FFF; margin:0 auto; } 
.inner { width:960px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; /* main width */ }     
.responsive .inner { max-width:960px; width:auto; }
body.responsive.isMobile .wrapper { overflow:hidden; }       
/*************************************************/
```

Please find complete css code [here](http://laptopsisland.com/wp-content/themes/maya/style.css).

Can anyone teach me how to increase the width using above css code?

Comment: Did u try increasing the width of the class `.boxed-layout .wrapper{ width:1200px;}`

Comment: The best questions are those which have all of the pertinent code right in the question, and nothing extraneous.  Going through the process of producing simple examples is also critical to learning and troubleshooting your own site.  
Can you put just the pertinent code into this question, so that it is useful to the next person?

Comment: Hi Vince. I would not recommend this way of learning CSS now. Please learn more about Basic CSS but do not use px in any of your code. Use responsive layouts. Use Bootstrap like Twitter or Foundation to make it look professional.

I have been in your position but now I feel, I should Have started with Responsive layouts only. As it is difficult to unlearn somethings before learning new one.

Comment: HI @DhruvenkumarShah,  thnq vm for your suggestion,.. May i know what exactly is 'responsive layout'?  I ahd basic knwoledge on css and i tried to change values using firebug , chrome inspector BUT site width not moving.. Luckily katiek (below) helped me in this, BUT i wanna know how to identify such things quickly... i have other sites  as well, iam really not sure how to increase width of them.. anyway I still unable to change width sizes of content, header and sidebar (though i able to increase width of actual layout..)

Comment: Hi Vince, okay so basically it is a way by which you have the same html or structural code but your presentation of the code changes depending on the device width you have so for e.g. cell phone or iPad or something like that. for a demo go to bostonglobe.com try resizing your window and check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of your site is currently constrained by these specifications:

```
.boxed-layout .bg-shadow { max-width: 1023px; }
.boxed-layout .wrapper { width: 1000px; }
```

If you increase those, your site will get wider.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot! I just chnaged width now and checked, BUT header, content and sidebar are messed up now.. I mean, even I wanna change content , header and sidebar widths....

and also i would like to know, how you would able to identify it..?

could u please teach on this..since I badly need this for my other sites as well..

Comment: I use Firebug (getfirebug.com - a Firefox add-on) to debug websites. There's a nice intro video at getfirebug.com/screencasts.

Comment: no, my actual query is: you told me "The width of your site is currently constrained by these specifications:" 

How you got to  know that? thats my actual doubt.. and how to identify these things for other sites as well..? I had a basic knwoledge on CSS.. Even I use firebug and chrome inspector, i tried to change values, but site width not moving....

Comment: The short answer is that I know CSS.  I've spent years learning, practicing front end web development. You would be well served by investing some time learning through some tutorial websites (Google is your friend). PS - Please also note that, on this site, proper English and grammar is strongly suggested.

Comment: OK Katiek, i agree with you.. you're experienced one's.. Actually can you tell me tips to change the width of a site..? for eg: in this site, may i know what you mainly looked into directly..? (or) have you just directly changed values each style  and checked by yourself..?